# UnboundLocalError at /vnos/

Tags: python, django

I'm building a test aplication to insert data into database and I keep on getting error "local variable 'form' referenced before assignment". I read a few articles and I do not understand how should I approach the problem in case the method is not POST.

All I'm trying to acchieve with this test application is to go to specified page, insert some numbers in the fields and then submit them. After that I want to check DB if they got submitted correctly.

views.py

```
def cost(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        amount = request.POST.get('amount', '')
        cost = request.POST.get('cost', '')
        cost_obj = Cost(amount = amount, cost = cost)
        cost_obj.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/vnos/')
    else:
        form = CostForm()

return render(request, "cost.html", {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Cost(models.Model):
cost = models.FloatField()
amount = models.FloatField()
```

forms.py

```
class CostForm(forms.Form):
date = forms.DateField()
amount = forms.FloatField()

class Meta:
    model = Cost
    fields = ['cost', 'amount']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statement is indented too far. Move it back one level.

Two other points: you should be getting the data from the form after validation, not direct from the POST:

```
    amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']
    cost = form.cleaned_data['cost']
```

And secondly, you could make it even simpler by using a ModelForm.

Comment: May I ask where should I put these 2 lines? Replace the lines that I have or put them somewhere else? Thanks

Comment: Yes, replace the lines you have. As I say though, if you made CostForm a ModelForm, you could replace all four lines with just `form.save()`.

Comment: I'm not following, would you mind telling me exactly what to do? I'm still doing tutorials so I don't know hot to change it to ModelForm

Comment: OK ignore that for now then. Just replace your two lines with mine.